# WxPhyton DatePickerCtrl not selectable

Tags: python, wxpython

I am constructing an `wx.DatePickerCtrl` by:

```
 self.DateTimePicker = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self, size=(100,-1), style = wx.DP_DROPDOWN |wx.DP_SHOWCENTURY)
 self.DateTimePicker.SetToolTipString("Select date of creation")
 self.Bind(wx.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.__OnDateTimePickerClicked, self.DateTimePicker)
```

with an Function called by the DateChanged Event.
But when I construct my Window and want to click to the DatePicker, it is not clickable.
Can someone fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide self._OnDateTimePickerClicked() method's details.

Comment: @ρss thats probably not his issue (It triggers after the date has changed...)

Comment: found the solution -.- if you're building this object on the wrong parrent, it cannot works -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing something wrong (somewhere else ... is there something covering it?)

```
import wx
class Blah(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.DateTimePicker = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self, size=(100,-1), style = wx.DP_DROPDOWN |wx.DP_SHOWCENTURY)
        self.DateTimePicker.SetToolTipString("Select date of creation")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_DATE_CHANGED, self.__OnDateTimePickerClicked, self.DateTimePicker)

    def __OnDateTimePickerClicked(self,e):
        e.Skip()


a = wx.App(redirect=False)
f = Blah(None,-1,"ASDASDASDASDASD")
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

really if you want to get help you will need to demonstrate with (minimal)example code that actually behaves the way you claim (eg my example which you can just copy and paste to a py file and see that you can indeed click the button)

Comment: You're right, I also thinking I doing something wrong somewhere else. But thanks for the help, I know there is not the mistake in building the object so I do...